# json replace all single quotes with double quotes

Tags: json, sed

How would I fix my json file which uses single quotes rather than the json-standard double quotes? Keep in mind that I don't want to replace the apostrophes

Here is an example of one of my json objects. I have ~ 9.4 million objects.

Notice the apostrophe in the "title"

```
{'asin': 'B00EI37RJM', 'title': "Bill's Best Original Organic BBQ Sauce - 1/2 Gallon", 'price': 21.99}
```

I have tried using

```
sed -i "s/'/\"/g" sample.json
```

But the apostrophe is replaced. I need to account for apostrophe from names ending in 's' i.e. James' Frances' Marcus'

Comment: I also need to account for conjunctions ending in the apostrophe such a Ol' as in "I am in a big ol' mess here"

Comment: Attempt code ? I tried in Linux

Comment: One *might* be able to do this with sed, but sed does not seem like the right tool for this job. A real parser, in a language like Perl, would be much simpler.